# How do I open a localhost port for TibcoBW6 REST app

Tags: eclipse, tibco, tibco-business-works

I have created a simple TibcoBW6 REST api that compiles and runs successful. [image]

The console logs indicate that the application is running but I try to invoke the api on Postman I get no response.
Telnet the port also can't connect.
[image]

I don't know whether my HTTP configurations are Ok, here is my connector properties
[image]

and the module properties.
[image]

I've scratched my head for hours searching for help online, but nothing came up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once your service runs succesfully, type

> lendpoints

in the console tab, you can check where your service is running.
If you don't get any result, there might be some problem with use of module properties, try to write directly localhost instead of using the module properties.